# ReactJS Unexpected token 'export' (at bundle.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**SOLUTION:**

I created my project using `create-react-app` which uses `react-scripts` version 0.9.5. This version of react-scripts uses a very old version of Webpack which is not ES-module-aware. After updating `react-scripts` to latest version, the problem solved.

---

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

I created a react project using `create-react-app`. Everything works fine except when I try to install and use `react-leaflet` package. The browser throws this exception:

**Uncaught SyntaxError: export declarations may only appear at top level of a module [bundle.js]**

I got the same error with `swiper` package, so I think the problem is not related to packages itself. I tried to fix the issue by adding `"type": "module"` to package.json but nothing changed.

This is the part of bundle.js file which causes error:
[image]

React version: 18.2.0
Node version: 16.17.0

Comment: Share the commands you've used to install the modules

Comment: @dreygur I copied commands from official docs.

Answer (score 1):

The packages are `react-leaflet` and `swiper`.
`react-leaflet` requires `leaflet` to be installed.
I have installed and used these just before answering your question and they are working fine.

Comment: It was a typo. I updated my question.